# can't files in AWS s3 bucket be overwritten?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I uploaded a new js file with the same name into the s3 bucket, but when I check the file via the Object URL in the file info page, the contents seem not to be changed

I then permanently deleted the js file in the s3 bucket and then reupload a newer version with the same file name, but when I open the Object URL the contents remains the same as the previous file.

I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload a file to S3 with the same name as an existing file you will overwrite the existing file. Caching may disguise this. If you have bucket versioning enabled you can access the old version of the object with the correct API call or via the S3 web console.

A small point, S3 terminology is it stores objects, and it has keys rather than filenames.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that old file is being cached by your browser which is preventing you from seeing the updated file contents. Try to clear browser cache or open it in incognito mode.

If this is not works check if the file versioning is enabled on your s3 bucket. If it is enabled each version of the file uploaded to the bucket will have a unique version. So you can try to access that file with version id parameter in url.